# how to use .htaccess to redirect a non exist page from a specific folder to homepage?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a directory called mydomain.com/node, under this directory, there are many non exist page, such as node/5678   node/53322 and so on.  When user visit these non-exist page, i would like to redirect them to homepage, i.e. mydomain.com

please note, there are also many valid pages under node/  but i only want to redirect non-exist pages under node/

I have tried the following two, none of them works for me

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/node/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,QSA]


RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^/node/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.+)         mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!